# What is the difference between em.find and em.createQuery

Tags: java, jpa, openjpa

```
em.find(Enity.classs, Id)

em.createQuery("SELECT e From Entity e WHERE e.Id=:id")
```

Are they equivalent? If not, How are they different?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The former might be faster because JPA provider does not have to parse the JPA query. But the resulting SQL should be exactly the same.

Also I think *some* providers might treat them differently with regards to caching - caching by key vs. query caching.

Finally the API is much more pleasant with `find()` - it either returns single entry or `null`. The latter either returns exactly one result (`getSingleResult()` - or throws) or returns a list (`getResultList()`).

Comment: The `find` method could return result from cache that does not reflect the state in database if a native query, or perhaps sql trigger, has changed the database without explicit notification for Hibernate. On the other hand, `createQuery` might go to the database directly and find no result.

Also if a new entity has been created, it might not be found using query if auto flush mode is not enabled.